# Eclipse, Tomcat & Maven workspace resolution: wrong folder structure?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am trying to build a spring-mvc project that has another project (core, as .jar) as dependency.

If I disable "Resolve dependencies from workspace projects" in eclipse, install the core into my maven repo and run it from eclipse, the application works!

What I want to do, is re enable "Resolve dependencies from workspace projects", but there is the problem: When I try to run the project on tomcat (after maven clean, project clean), I get a "FileNotFoundException". The file in question is under src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-core.xml
It seems, the File can not be found in the classpath.
I looked up the deployment location and found out, that everything of the core is under the following folders:

- WEB-INF

  - classes

So the file I am missing can be found here:
/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-core.xml

But it schould be here:
/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-core.xml

Why is the structure of my core dependency so messed up when I enable the workspace resolution and how can I fix this?

I am using eclipse mars with m2e..

Thanks for any help.

**Edit:**
Project structure (core) looks like this:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAMzb.png)

Comment: 1. Why /META-INF ?
Put context spring (xml conf) here :
src/main/resources/applicationContext-core.xml

Comment: It doesn't matter and it works when I use the (correctly build) .jar... roo for example does it this way (http://docs.spring.io/spring-roo/reference/html/beginning.html)

Comment: added a picture of project structure...

Comment: show context.xml for war project and wich u call applicationContext-core.xml from core-project

Comment: What I did in the applicationContext.xml of the project is this:
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext-core.xml" /> I think the other stuff is not relevant... remember: it works, if I disable the workspace project resolution...